# Why is this automatic flag still shown as "active"?

Tags: support, flags, automatic-flags

Looking at [the flags raised for my own posts on Drupal Answers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/flagged-posts/199), I found the following one.

[image: screenshot]

The [flag was handled by a Community Coordinator](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/admin/posts/295/show-flags), but the flag is still shown as active.

[image: screenshot]

Should not the flag be shown as helpful or declined? Since there isn't any post to close or delete, automatically handling the flag should not be possible; if that were the case, the Community user should be shown as deletion user. As this is not the case, a moderator should have manually handled the flag.

Comment: `.../flagged-posts/userid` is mod-only? That link in your post gives me a 404, and I also get a 404 when trying to access mine on Stack Overflow

Comment: @Doorknob: Yes, it’s mod-only. The link for yours would be to access your posts that other people have flagged, which… isn’t allowed. :)

Comment: @minitechη I'm wondering why...

Comment: @H2CO3 Because moderator flags are anonymous, by design. Only moderators can see them, and moderators have to agree to keep this information confidential. You're not supposed to be able to see someone flagging your content, just like you can't see who downvoted you. That helps to keep down revenge and unnecessary bad blood. Note that it works for Kiamlaluno here, because he's a moderator on Drupal Answers. (He doesn't mention that in the question, I just stalk him.)

Comment: @H2CO3 Yes, I am a Drupal Answers moderator. To add, the flag I am showing is the automatic one generated when users edit more than X of their own posts in short time. The screenshot doesn't show the user who flagged, but that is our friend the Community user. When I look at  the flags raised for my own posts, I don't see who flagged, even if I am moderator.